# Deploy configuration of CiviCRM components between staging and production

Tags: civicrm

There are multiple instances of a Drupal/CiviCRM installation, one at localhost, at the developers' computer, one staging site and one production site. The production site is already in use.
How can I move changes between different instances? For example a new contribution page or a priceset or a membership setting? In Drupal, there is features. What is the best practise for CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no handy thing like the Features module to export configuration changes in CiviCRM.  You can write an extension that configures everything using the API.  However, that's usually overkill for something like you describe.

Comment: After the deployment, i have to expose how it was done. You can do it surprisingly comfortable via SQL. The tables are often self-contained, i spent 1 hour to collect the needed tables and then a mysql dump was sufficient to transfer the things. It might not work for certain type of modifications, worked in my simple case, where i had to add new contribution pages, alter pricesets, modify custom fields.

Comment: Nice.  It can be sometimes tricky to do that between a development copy and an active production site because the IDs for contribution pages, custom field, option groups, etc. will all be different, but in your case, it sounds like it was all you needed.